# How to completely remove Google Tests from Visual Studio solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, googletest, visual-studio-2019

I am working on a C++ project for my own education and I want to do unit tests on it. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Community. I have successfully used the native visual studio unit test framework on other projects in the past. Today on a whim I tried to use the google test framework instead. After some unsuccessful effort in trying to get it to work, I decided that I don't have time to learn it right now after all and would like to just use the native test framework instead.

I removed the google test project from my solution and deleted it from the source folder, so that project is gone. Then I added a new native unit test project. I added a simple test and the build succeeded, but the Test Explorer didn't show any tests. I selected Run All anyway, and the Output window has entries about "Test Adapter for Google Test: Test execution starting...", "Google Test execution completed", "Could not locate debug symbols", and "No test is available". It seems to be still trying to execute Google tests, not native unit tests even though I removed and deleted the google test project and added a native unit test project to my solution.

How to I change it so that it runs the native unit tests instead of trying to run google tests?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but could solve it by uninstalling the google test adapter from the visual studio setup.

Also you need to ensure that the Test -> "Test-Settings" -> "Default Processor Architecture" is set to the correct one (If not, the test explorer may not show up your test-cases).